# Why is my Kafka consumer reconnecting to the CNAME behind the bootstrap server?

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a specific use-case where I re-create a kafka cluster daily. The `bootstrap.servers` address (which I have configured, and which does not change) therefore points to a different broker address every day, through a CNAME DNS record. (e.g. `b1.mycluster.internal` -> `b1.mskdev.q1w2e3.c3.aws.com` on Monday, then `b1.mskdev.a4s5d6.c7.aws.com` on Tuesday)

I have noticed that once the cluster goes offline, the Kafka consumer app which I am using is trying to reconnect to the resolved CNAME instead of the configured address in `bootstrap.servers`. To reuse the example above, the consumer keeps trying to reestablish connection to `b1.mskdev.q1w2e3.c3.aws.com` but what I actually need is for it to reconnect to the new broker `b1.mskdev.a4s5d6.c7.aws.com` which is the new CNAME record for initially-configured `bootstrap.servers=b1.mycluster.internal`.

I am using the usual kafka-client Java library and initializing a `KafkaConsumer` with the bootstrap server set as described. Once the cluster goes offline, the logs are populated with errors regarding the connection to the CNAME behind the bootstrap server, and not the bootstrap server itself. With the default reconnect properties, the consumer tries to reconnect indefinitely to the expired broker address, and thus the only solution is for me to restart the consumer so that the new CNAME address is resolved through the bootstrap server address.

Comment: That's a strange use case. Are the brokers having different storage? Could you setup some type of proxy rather than mess with DNS names and caches?

Comment: @OneCricketeer the brokers are configured identically. I'm doing this for "economical" reasons to avoid extra AWS billing, keeping the brokers online just through active development hours.

Comment: Have you used [MSK Serverless](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/serverless.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Kafka clients only use the `bootstrap.servers` on startup and after this they discover all of the brokers themselves and cache this information based on fetching metadata. As Kafka does not know about your CNAME it will return internal DNS names.

In order to control the metadata that gets returned i.e. return the CNAME rather than the resolved name. You can set `advertised.listeners` and this will cause the metadata api to return listener addresses as your CNAME rather than the internal one.

See

- https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs_advertised.listeners
- https://i-sammy.medium.com/what-is-advertised-listeners-in-kafka-9e2a216e070
- https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-listeners-explained/

Please note, it is very easy to break Kafka by setting `advertised.listeners` incorrectly. You should only set this for the client listeners (`CLIENT` or `CLIENT_SECURE`) and not touch `REPLICATION` etc or risk breaking internal replication.

I recommend you set this in static config so that it can easily be rolled back or updated.

Whilst this can be done with dynamic config, it still requires a broker restart to take effect. If you break it in dynamic you will need to remove directly from ZK.

This is safe to do with MSK-P when done correctly, see their Goldman Sachs blog (not all relevant, just the advertised.listeners part) https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/how-goldman-sachs-builds-cross-account-connectivity-to-their-amazon-msk-clusters-with-aws-privatelink/

Comment: Since I am using a managed kafka cluster, the `advertised.listeners` are configured automatically. The problem is, as you say, that the client library caches the resolved broker address, despite having a still-valid bootstrap server address configured. I would like to be able to reconnect the client without altering the internal properties of the kafka cluster.

Comment: You can still change `advertised.listeners` in MSK. This is the correct way to achieve what you want. See goldman sachs did similar where they changed advertised.listeners https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/how-goldman-sachs-builds-cross-account-connectivity-to-their-amazon-msk-clusters-with-aws-privatelink/